# PHP - Creating a default object to substitute an empty value inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I've create an array importing it from a CSV file.

```
$csv = str_getcsv(file_get_contents('table.csv'));
```

The `$csv` array gives this output

```
Array
(
Values
    [90] => 
    [91] => 
    [92] => 
    [93] => 
    [94] => 
    [95] => 
    [96] => 
    [97] => 
    [98] => 136
    [99] => 384
    [100] => 431
)
```

How can I substitute all the empty objects inside the array (from 90 to 97) with a sign/symbol (for example a `-`)?

Comment: Just iterate over the array and replace the elements value if required.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) The answer is fairly simple: Iterate over array, check if current element is empty, if so, substitute. If not, continue.

Comment: `array_map(function ($item) { return $item ?: '-'; }, $array);`

Comment: Thanks for all your replies! I apologize with the entire community for this dumb question but I'm new of the PHP world and I'm just learning. So, again...I apologize!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($csv as $key=>$value)
{
  if($csv[$key]=="")
  {
    $csv[$key]="-";
   }
}
print_r($csv);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
Values
    [90] => -
    [91] => -
    [92] => -
    [93] => -
    [94] => -
    [95] => -
    [96] => -
    [97] => -
    [98] => 136
    [99] => 384
    [100] => 431
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! I apologize with the entire community for this dumb question but I'm new of the PHP world and I'm just learning. So, again...I apologize!